# How do I call user-defined function only if it exists?

Tags: sqlite, user-defined-functions

SQLite allows to [define custom functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) that can be called from SQL statements. I use this to get notified of trigger activity in my application:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AfterInsert AFTER INSERT ON T
BEGIN
  -- main trigger code involves some extra db modifications
  -- ...
  
  -- invoke application callback
  SELECT ChangeNotify('T', 'INSERT', NEW.id);
END;
```

However, user-defined functions are added only to current database connection. There may be other clients who haven't defined `ChangeNotify` and I don't want them to get a "no such function" error.

Is is possible to call a function only if it's defined? Any alternative solution is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is designed as an embedded database, so it is assumed that your application controls what is done with the database.

SQLite has no SQL function to check for user-defined functions.

If you want to detect changes made only from your own program, use [sqlite3_update_hook](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html).

Comment: Thanks. If UDfs were only stored somewhere like `sqlite_master` then I could probably get away with a `CASE` statement with `EXISTS` inside it...

Answer (score 2):

Prior to calling your user defined function, you can check if the function exists by selecting from pragma_function_list;

```
select exists(select 1 from pragma_function_list where name='ChangeNotify');
1
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible by combining a query against `pragma_function_list` and a `WHEN` statement on the trigger --

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER AfterInsert AFTER INSERT ON T
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pragma_function_list WHERE name = 'ChangeNotify')
BEGIN
  SELECT ChangeNotify('T', 'INSERT', NEW.id);
END;
```

except that query preparation attempts to resolve functions prior to execution. So, afaik, this isn't possible to do in a trigger.

I need to do the same thing and asked here: https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/a997b1a01d
Hopefully they come back with a solution.

---

## Update

SQLite forum suggestion is to use `create temp trigger` when your extension loads -- https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/96160a6536e33f71

This is actually a great solution as temp triggers are:

- not visible to other connections
- are cleaned up when the connection creating them ends